# Improve PSTricks code

Tags: pstricks, programming

Consider the following very ugly PSTricks code:

```
% latex file.tex
% dvips file.dvi
% ps2pdf file.ps
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-text,pst-slpe,pstricks-add}

\newcommand*\kurve{%
 {\psset{linewidth = 2\pslinewidth}
  \psline(12,4)(12,0.5)
  \psarc(11.5,0.5){0.5}{270}{360}
  \psline(11.5,0)(0.5,0)
  \psarc(0.5,0.5){0.5}{180}{270}
  \psline(0,0.5)(0,4)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(12,9)
  \multido{\i = 0+15}{24}{%
    \rput{\i}(2.5,6.5){\psline[linecolor = yellow](1.18,0)(2.5,0)}}
  \psBall(2.5,6.5){yellow}{6ex}
  \pstextpath[r](0,1ex){%
    \psarc[linecolor = gray!70](6,33.39){30}{258.5}{281.5}}{Husholdningsfilm}
  \pscustom[
    linestyle = none,
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = blue!60
  ]{
    \psplot[
      algebraic,
      plotpoints = 200
    ]{0}{12}{0.1*sin(10*x)+0.5}
    \kurve
    }
 {\psset{linewidth = 2\pslinewidth}
  \psline(0,0.5)(0,4)
  \psline(12,4)(12,0.5)}
  \pscustom[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = white
  ]{
    \psarc(7.8,0.2){0.2}{270}{360}
    \psline(7.8,0)(4.2,0)
    \psarc(4.2,0.2){0.2}{180}{270}
    \psline(4,0.2)(4,1.5)(8,1.5)(8,0.2)
   }
 {\psset{
    linewidth = 2\pslinewidth,
    linecolor = white
  }
  \psline(4.012,1.5)(7.988,1.5)
  \psline(4,0.2)(4.2,0)}
  \psarc(4.2,0.2){0.2}{180}{270}
  \psline(4,0.17)(4,0.23)
  \psline(4.17,0)(4.23,0)
  \psline[
    linewidth = 2\pslinewidth,
    linecolor = white
  ](7.8,0)(8,0.2)
  \psarc(7.8,0.2){0.2}{270}{360}
  \psline(8,0.17)(8,0.23)
  \psline(7.77,0)(7.83,0)
  \psframe[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = gray!80
  ](5.5,3.395)(6.5,3.775)
  \psarc(6,3.775){0.15}{0}{180}
  \psframe[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = gray!80
  ](5.2,0.02)(6.8,0.82)
  \psarc[
    linewidth = 1.5\pslinewidth
  ](6,0.8){0.25}{0}{180}
  \kurve
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I have the desired output but the code is very ugly.

**Question**: How do I improve on, i.e. simplify, the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have text along a curve, use the `\pstextpath` command from `pst-text`. Here is a shorter code:

```
\documentclass[x11names]{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-slpe, pst-text}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %

\newcommand*\suitcase[1][]{\psset{#1}%
\psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray!80](-0.8,0)(0.8,0.8)
\psarc[linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth](0,0.8){0.25}{0}{180}
}
\newcommand*\smallpot[1][]{%
\psset{linewidth = 2\pslinewidth, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=white, #1}%
\pscustom{\psline[linearc=0.2](-2,1.5)(-2,0)(2,0)(2,1.5)}
}%
\newcommand*\mykurve[1][]{\psset{#1}\psline[linearc=0.5](0,4)(0,0)(12,0)(12,4)}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(12,9)
\psset{linejoin=1}
  \multido{\i=0+15}{24}{%
    \rput{\i}(2.5,6.5){\psline[linecolor = yellow](1.2,0)(2.5,0)}
    }
  \psBall(2.5,6.5){yellow}{8ex}
  %
  \pstextpath[r](0,-2.5ex){\psarc[linecolor = gray!70 ](6,33.39){30}{258.5}{281.5}}{Husholdningsfilm\quad}
  \pscustom[linestyle=none, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=blue!60]{%
    \psplot[algebraic, plotpoints=200,plotstyle=curve]{12}{0}{0.1*sin(10*x)+0.5}
    \mykurve
    }%
   \rput(6,0){\smallpot[linecolor=SteelBlue4]}
 \rput(6,3.405){\psscalebox{0.625}{\suitcase}}%(6,3.3875)
  \rput(6,\pslinewidth){\suitcase}
  \mykurve[linewidth=2\pslinewidth, linecolor=SteelBlue4]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]